# Fragments, listviews and design choices

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I have an activity hosting a fragment that will contain a listview.  When the user selects an item of the listview I want another listview to appear (In the form of another fragment maybe?) so the user can select their choice from a narrowed down list of options.

How is this best done.  Should I have one activity hosting a number of fragments or a number of activites hosting many fragments or can this all be done in one fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to do this with multiple fragments in your activity (A), one for the initial list (FA), and one for the narrowed list (FB).

When the user does select an item from the initial list, show the detailed list fragment corresponding to that selection. FA would, upon selection of an item, call A and request to have FB shown, handing over the required information to decide what content FB is going to show.

You can solve navigation nicely with the TransactionManagers backstack this way, i.e. if the user does press the back button from your narrowed down list, taking them right back to their initial list.